# How to get the number between ><

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the number between this >< using python but this number is always changing.

This is the webpage I want to scrape:

```html
<div><div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-3"><div class="px-3 mb-6 w-1/3"><div class="card card card-panel" lens=""><a href="/resources/leads-by-users" class="" style="text-decoration: none;"><div class="card-row"><div class="card-6"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2.2em" height="2.2em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-users"><path d="M17 21v-2a4 4 0 0 0-4-4H5a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v2"></path><circle cx="9" cy="7" r="4"></circle><path d="M23 21v-2a4 4 0 0 0-3-3.87"></path><path d="M16 3.13a4 4 0 0 1 0 7.75"></path></svg></div> <div class="card-6 right"><**div class="featured card-12">15</div>** <div class="card-12">Abertas</div></div></div> <div class="card-12 title">
                Leads
            </div> <div class="card-12 center">
                0 Picked / 44 Contactadas
            </div></a> <!----> <!----></div></div><div class="px-3 mb-6 w-1/3"><div class="card card card-panel" lens=""><!----> <a href="/resources/lending-orders" class="" style="text-decoration: none;"><div class="card-row"><div class="card-6"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2.2em" height="2.2em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-send"><line x1="22" y1="2" x2="11" y2="13"></line><polygon points="22 2 15 22 11 13 2 9 22 2"></polygon></svg></div> <div class="card-6 right">**<div class="featured card-12">31</div>** <div class="card-12">Abertas em POS</div></div></div> <div class="card-12 title">
                Lending
            </div> <div class="card-12 center">
                23 / 218 In Lending
            </div></a> <!----></div></div><div class="px-3 mb-6 w-1/3"><div class="card card card-panel" lens=""><!----> <!----> <div class="cursor-pointer"><div class="card-row"><div class="card-6"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2.2em" height="2.2em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-user-check"><path d="M16 21v-2a4 4 0 0 0-4-4H5a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v2"></path><circle cx="8.5" cy="7" r="4"></circle><polyline points="17 11 19 13 23 9"></polyline></svg></div> <div class="card-6 right">**<div class="featured card-12">4</div>** <div class="card-12">Criados (este mês)</div></div></div> <div class="card-12 title">
                Criar Lead
            </div> <div class="card-12 center">
                1 Fechadas com vendas (este mês)
            </div></div> <!----></div></div></div> <!----></div>
```

I want every number that is in front of:

```html
<div class="featured card-12">15</div> /// <div class="featured card-12">31</div> and <div class="featured card-12">4</div>
```

```py
driver.get("https://ispot2.faturaiqos.pt")
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
out = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"featured card-12"})
print(out)
```

Return:

```py
[<div class="featured card-12"></div>, <div class="featured card-12"></div>, <div class="featured card-12"></div>] -- The numbers I want never show.
```

The numbers I want never show.

Comment: first you should check what you get in `page_source` maybe you get HTML without number. Maybe page use JavaScript to add number and you have to `sleep()` to wait for information. Or maybe you should use different parser in `bs(...., parser)` - `BeautifulSoup` may use different parser `html.parser`, `lxml`, `html5lib` and sometimes one of them has problem to parse all data and other will gives all data. You could also try to use function which you have in Selenium instead of `BeautifulSoup` - `driver.find_elements_by_....` - maybe they will better work with data in browser.

Comment: @furas i tried time.sleep(5) didnt work, i dont know how to input lxml or html5lib into my code:
´driver.get("https://ispot2.faturaiqos.pt")
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")`

Do i just sub lxml or html5lib for html in the code above?

Comment: I mean `bs(html, "lxml")` or `bs(html, "html5lib")` instead of `bs(html, "html.parser")`

Comment: I Got it :) Thank you. I have another question:
I want to run this .py every hour auto how can i do it?